# Is it ok to repeat fields in graphql queries?

Tags: graphql, fragment, repeat

```
query MyQuery {
  capsules {
    missions {
      name
      
    }
    missions {
      name
      flight
    }
  }
}
```

Can I leave the above as is with no side effects?or should i change it to:

```
query MyQuery {
  capsules {
    missions {
      name
      flight
    }
  }
}
```

It all works as it should but I worry about performance on the server-side.

Comment: Depending on your server implementation it could process it twice or realize of the trick and calculate only once. What you certainly lose is on network traffic, as you send the name and missions object twice over the network, and the client must deserialize it twice as well. I would use the second version for clarity too.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will just find a way to combine all my fragments.And generate the second version of the query.